# Unable to use spring data jpa CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use CrudRepository from Spring data jpa.I am getting error in spring-servlet.xml file. I think I am missing some configuration.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans "             
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
     xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
">
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.entransys"></ctx:component-scan>
    <!-- <repositories base-package="com.entransys.repositories" /> -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.entransys.repository"/>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdata" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I added the following dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**error**

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
> ```
>
> Line 15 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 4;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)

Comment: *I think I am missing some configuration.* - why? do you have a question?

Comment: Post the error :)

Comment: can you post which you are getting?

Comment: I have edited and added the error. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have trailing space here : `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans "`, line 2 in `spring-servlet.xml`. Remove it and it will be fine.

Comment: After removing space I am getting following error                                                `Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!`

Comment: This new error as nothing to do with the first one. A quick look in stackoverflow shows it is most likely related to wrong Maven dependencies.